# Using CodeIgniter get_where to chain 'and' and 'or' statements

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to access data in a local database (on my vm), and I have to use CodeIgniter's query building classes to get the data. I have this query which I have figured out in sql:

```
select message, created
from logs
where username = 'user'
    and (
        created > '1487695796'
        and created < '1487782196'
        )
    and (
        message = 'login failure'
        or message = 'login success'
        or message = 'log out'
        )
order by created asc
```

My biggest question is how can I chain the 'and's and 'or's in a get_where statement in CodeIgniter? I have looked and saw I could put things in an array for the 'WHERE' portion, but I haven't seen how I can place things in for the 'or's (since everything in the array is an 'and'. I MUST use get_where (can't do 'get->where'), so if there is a way to do it, please let me know!

Thank you for taking the time to read my question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Codeigniter 3.0 the query builder class supports [Query grouping](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping)

from the docs:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('my_table')
        ->group_start()
                ->where('a', 'a')
                ->or_group_start()
                        ->where('b', 'b')
                        ->where('c', 'c')
                ->group_end()
        ->group_end()
        ->where('d', 'd')
->get();

// Generates:
// SELECT * FROM (`my_table`) WHERE ( `a` = 'a' OR ( `b` = 'b' AND `c` = 'c' ) ) AND `d` = 'd'
```

**Edit:**
in your example you would use:

```
$this->db->select('message, created')->from('logs')
        ->where('username', 'user')
        ->group_start()
                ->where('created >', '1487695796')
                ->where('created <', '1487782196')
        ->group_end()
        ->group_start()
                ->where('message', 'login failure')
                ->or_where('message', 'login success')
                ->or_where('message', 'log out')
        ->group_end()               
        ->order_by('created', 'ASC')  
->get();
```

or

```
$this->db->select('message, created')
        ->group_start()
                ->where('created >', '1487695796')
                ->where('created <', '1487782196')
        ->group_end()
        ->group_start()
                ->where('message', 'login failure')
                ->or_where('message', 'login success')
                ->or_where('message', 'log out')
        ->group_end()               
        ->order_by('created', 'ASC')  
->get_where('logs', array('username' => 'user') );

// both generate:
//SELECT `message`, `created` 
//FROM `logs` 
//WHERE `username` = 'user' 
//AND ( `created` > '1487695796' AND `created` < '1487782196' ) 
//AND ( `message` = 'login failure' OR `message` = 'login success' OR `message` = 'log out' ) 
//ORDER BY `created` ASC
```

to check if the Codeigniter generated query matches your SQL, you can use:

```
echo $this->db->last_query(); // echos last query string
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
$q=$this->db
             ->select('message,created')
             ->where('username','user')
             ->where('created >','1487695796')
             ->where('created <','1487782196')
             ->where('message','login failure')
             ->or_where('message','login success')
             ->or_where('message','log out')
             ->order_by('created, ASC')
             ->get('logs');
      return $q->result();
```

Comment: this doesn't create the groups in the where clause, there are no brackets `()` generated

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('message, created');
$this->db->where(['username' => '\'user\'', 'created >' => '1487695796', 'created <' => '1487782196']);
$this->db->where("(message='login failure' OR message='login success' OR message='log out')", NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->order_by('created', 'ASC');
$query = $this->db->get('logs');
return $query->result();
```