# How to use LIKE in get_where

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

My Code :

```
public function amil_export($program){
$query = $this->get_where('tbl_amil', [ 'jenis_lembaga' => '%Perorang%',
                                    'program' => $program
                                ]);
  $query = $this->execute();
  return $query;
}
```

And I want to make Query in SQL like This

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_amil` WHERE `jenis_lembaga` LIKE '%Perorang%' OR `program` = $program
```

can Someone fix my code

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution for this. I've used `$this->db->group_start();` and `$this->db->group_end();`

```
public function amil_export($keyword, $program) {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->like('jenis_lembaga',$keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('program',$program);
    $this->db->group_end();
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_amil');
    // echo $this->db->last_query();
    return $query->result_array();

}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

`get_where` will not be able to give you the result with `OR` condition in it. ([**REFERENCE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490306/using-codeigniter-get-where-to-chain-and-and-or-statements))

You can use `like` and `or_where` to get the query as you want, like so -

```
$query = $this->db->like('jenis_lembaga', 'Perorang')->or_where('program', $program)->get('tbl_amil')->result();

// Produces:
// SELECT * FROM `tbl_amil` WHERE `jenis_lembaga` LIKE '%Perorang%' ESCAPE '!' OR `program` = $program
```

You can also use `query grouping` ([**REFERENCE**](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping)) as @Ankit Jindal suggests.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function amil_export($program)
{
    $this->db->like('jenis_lembaga ','Perorang','both');       
    $this->db->or_where('program',$program);
    $query=$this->db->get('tbl_amil'); 
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Most answers will benefit from an explanation to help visitors hone in on the important elements of your solution. Explanations increase long term value allowing uture visitors to learn from & apply your knowledge to their own code, keeps quality of SO high, & encourages the use of SO platform as a knowledge base, rather than a "give me the code" or, free coding service. Eplanations are usually quicker to digest/understand than strictly interpreting code, & helps distinguish your solution with other solutions. Well crafted answers are more often upvoted